# usercontrol template system c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

I want to use string replace to replace the tag `{tag:shoppingcart}` and in that it would load the user control:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="basket" TagName="cart" src="~/controls/basket.ascx" %>

<basket:cart id="test" runat="server"></basket:cart>
```

I would be defining the controls at the top of the page that needs them.

My question is what is my best way to achieve the following if it is at all possible

```
string templatehtml;
templatehtml = template[0].Cms;
string newhtml;

newhtml = templatehtml.Replace("{tag_pagecontent}", currentPage[0].Body);

newhtml = templatehtml.Replace("{tag_shoppingcart}",   <basket:cart    id="test" runat="server"></basket:cart>); 

litcontent.Text = newhtml;
```

It's the `<basket:cart` code i am having trouble with.

Comment: If you want to do template replacements with code that needs to be actually processed by ASP.Net, you will need to use control processing functionality like `Page.LoadControl("MyControl.ascx")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We actually do a very similar thing, except we have placeholder divs on the page.

In the page_init method, we get a reference to the placeholder div, load the user control into the page, and then add the usercontrol to the div's controls.

For example (very rough code):

```
// Get a reference to the div
Control oUserControlDiv = this.FindControl("divUserControl");

// Load the user control
Control oControl = this.LoadControl("controls/basket.ascx");
oControl.EnableViewState = true;

// Clear the existing control(s) from the div
oUserControlDiv.Controls.Clear();
// And add the new one
oUserControlDiv.Controls.Add(oControl);
```

Comment: high thats looks great but can you tell me how I would go about parsing the text in that case to find if their is the tag:shopping cart in it does this allow for all functions of the control to behave normal and postbacks ?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this instead:

```
var basket = new Basket();

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb);

using (HtmlTextWriter writer = new HtmlTextWriter(sw))
{
   basket.RenderControl(writer);
}

string basketHtml = sb.ToString();

newhtml =    templatehtml.Replace("{tag_shoppingcart}",   basketHtml);
```